# Using property from enum file in React returns titles is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enums

I have a simple custom component in React that accepts a string as a property and displays text. I am trying to load my text content from a `const` in an enums js file that is located in my src folder. I import the file in my parent component and in the `index.js` but when I try to use it I get `'titles' is not defined`, how can I use the constant from the file properly? Here is the relevant code:

```
import React from 'react';
import enums from '../../enums.js'
import CustomHeading from '../CustomHeading/CustomHeading.jsx'


class SecondColumn extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return <div className="second-column">

      <div className="second-column__about-me">
        <CustomHeading text={titles.ABOUT_ME} className="second-column__centered-heading" />
        <img className="second-column__first_part__test-img-col" src={require("../../assets/images/fake-image.png")} alt="fake img for now" />
        <div className="second-column_first_part_text-parent">
          <p className="second-column_first_part_text-parent__text-body">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id  Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id
          Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id  Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id
          Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id  Molestiae molestias tempora ratione dolorum, tenetur laborum blanditiis id
           </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="second-column__first_part">
        <CustomHeading text={'My astrological readings'} className="second-column__centered-heading" />

       </div>
       </div>
  }
};

export default SecondColumn;
```

And here is the `enums` file:

```
const titles = {
    ABOUT_ME: 'About me'
}

export default titles
```

I also tried calling it by enums.titles.ABOUT_ME but that didn't work either

Comment: You're not exporting anything from your `enum` file ?

Comment: `titles` should be exported as default in the `enums` file. Have you done that?

Comment: I had forgotten that step, I did it and I now get  titles is not defined

Comment: Yes because you're importing it as `enums` not `titles`, use `enums.ABOUT_ME` or import it as `titles`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling it by

```
enums.titles.ABOUT_ME
```

Call it using

```
enums.ABOUT_ME
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your `enums.js` file needs a default export.

```
const titles = {
    ABOUT_ME: 'About me'
};

export default titles;
```

In addition you are accessing the enums object improperly. Change `titles.ABOUT_ME` to `enums.ABOUT_ME` in your component. Or change the name of your imported const to `titles`.

Importing as `titles`:

```
// Replace this line
import enums from '../../enums.js';

// With this line
import titles from '../../enums.js';
```